# How do I "say . . . using" in Javascript for Automation?

Tags: applescript, automator, javascript

In Applescript, I can specify the voice the system uses to speak text as follows:

```
say "Hello" using "Alex"
```

In Javascript, I can do something similar:

```
var ScriptEditor = Application("Script Editor");
ScriptEditor.includeStandardAdditions = true;

ScriptEditor.say("Hello!")
```

But I don't know how to specify the specific voice; I always have to use the system. Is there a way to specify the `using` parameter, or another version of `say` that allows the code to specify the voice?

Comment: Don't use Javascript it's really not made to make automated workflows. It very basic and not at all better in any aspect.

Comment: I'm more familiar with JavaScript. I'd like to know if it's possible in JavaScript before I fall back to AppleScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014508-CH109-SW11) describes how to call commands which have both direct parameters (the text) and named parameters (the using). In this case, you would do this:

```
var ScriptEditor = Application("Script Editor");
ScriptEditor.includeStandardAdditions = true;

ScriptEditor.say("Hello", {using: "Alex"})
```

Comment: Thanks Alan! I'd tried to use ScriptEditor.say({text: "Hello", using: "Alex"}), but clearly I'd misread the directions.